# Should virtual be default or final be default?

Tags: oop, language-design

Does functions being virtual as default violate close for modification? 
Does functions being final as default violate open for extension?

Should functions be final as default if multiple inheritance is implemented?

How about classes?
Should them be virtual as default or final as default?

Or should both final and virtual be explicit? (i.e. Force coder to declare every functions or classes as final or virtual like how in most language there isn't a default return type.) Since explicit is better than implicit.

Final means a function or a class can't be inherited or overrode, virtual means a function or a class can be inherited or overrode.

Comment: 'Open' and 'close' have no meaning that I am aware of in this context.

Comment: @EJP that comes from kotlin...

Comment: `open` is from Kotlin, which doesn't appear in your tags. `close` isn't from anywhere, yet.

Comment: @EJP Yeah I realized and I edited the question.

Comment: But without addressing what I said. 'close' remains undefined. Primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @EJP sorry the question suppose to say final instead of close, I edited it wrong, thanks

Comment: If `final` is explicit, `virtual` is implicit, and *vice versa*. Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @EJP ok I clarified it.

Comment: I can't answer until you answer a more fundamental question: should inheritance be tightly coupled or loosely coupled? Most agree that independent classes should be loosely coupled but inheritance implies a tighter coupling. So, how much tighter?

Comment: @shawnhcorey Interesting. I think inheritance should be loosely coupled, so that answered my question I guess. If they were to be loosely coupled then final should be default and if they were to be tightly coupled then virtual should be default?

Comment: @ShuangLi Sounds about right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set classes being virtual as default will imply a tighter coupling across the code, as inheritance is encouraged, but the composition and interface over inheritance, hence inheritance should be discouraged, so in my opinion, classes should be final as default. Same with functions, they being virtual as default not only violate close for modification but encourages inheritance which will imply a tighter coupling across the code.

Explicitly stating them could be an option, but that just adds redundancy to your code..